# How to set zoom focus based on pinch location using hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hammer.js

I am able to perform pinch for div content when passing the element to the  method below, but whilst the pinch is performing the focus is always at the center.

How can I change the focus based on pinch location?

```
function hammerIt(elm) {
    hammertime = new Hammer(elm, {});
    hammertime.get('pinch').set({
        enable: true
    });
    var posX = 0,
        posY = 0,
        scale = 1,
        last_scale = 1,
        last_posX = 0,
        last_posY = 0,
        max_pos_x = 0,
        max_pos_y = 0,
        transform = "",
        el = elm;

    hammertime.on('doubletap pan pinch panend pinchend', function(ev) {
      if (ev.type == "doubletap") {
            transform =
                "translate3d(0, 0, 0) " +
                "scale3d(2, 2, 1) ";
            scale = 2;
            last_scale = 2;
            try {
                if (window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform').toString() != "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)") {
                    transform =
                        "translate3d(0, 0, 0) " +
                        "scale3d(1, 1, 1) ";
                    scale = 1;
                    last_scale = 1;
                }
            } catch (err) {}
            el.style.webkitTransform = transform;
            transform = "";
        }

        //pan    
        if (scale != 1) {
            posX = last_posX + ev.deltaX;
            posY = last_posY + ev.deltaY;
            max_pos_x = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * el.clientWidth / 2);
            max_pos_y = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * el.clientHeight / 2);
            if (posX > max_pos_x) {
                posX = max_pos_x;
            }
            if (posX < -max_pos_x) {
                posX = -max_pos_x;
            }
            if (posY > max_pos_y) {
                posY = max_pos_y;
            }
            if (posY < -max_pos_y) {
                posY = -max_pos_y;
            }
        }


        //pinch
        if (ev.type == "pinch") {
            scale = Math.max(.999, Math.min(last_scale * (ev.scale), 4));
        }
        if(ev.type == "pinchend"){last_scale = scale;}

        //panend
        if(ev.type == "panend"){
            last_posX = posX < max_pos_x ? posX : max_pos_x;
            last_posY = posY < max_pos_y ? posY : max_pos_y;
        }

        if (scale != 1) {
            transform =
                "translate3d(" + posX + "px," + posY + "px, 0) " +
                "scale3d(" + scale + ", " + scale + ", 1)";
        }

        if (transform) {
            el.style.webkitTransform = transform;
        }
    });
}
```